# Typical load examples for RL and RC series and parallel circuits

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor, load

I have already learned theoretical description of RL and RC circuits and their behavior. But now with a benefit of hindsight I have never truly learned about typical real world loads that have similar response.

So I am asking more seasoned engineers who are more knowledgeable in this. I am talking about practical devices used for example in different industries. I can guess that electric machines will have RL behavior and PCB will have RC behavior (series or parallel?). So let me know which loads have **dominant**:

- RC series component
- RL series component
- RC parallel component
- RL parallel component

LC component should only be considered as parasitic.
Any recommended literature on this subject is also welcome.

Thank you

Comment: RLC circuits are *models*. Almost every passive components behave like an RLC under some linearized range. Thus, there are hundreds of possible answers for this. Transmission lines, Motors, Generators, Loads.....

Comment: @Brethlosze Thank you for the comment. I am fully aware that my question is simplification of the subject so I will not argue about that point. The main point of this post was to appeal to experts that know and maybe modelled loads whose behavior is close to the mentioned types of circuits. Hence the bolded dominant qualifier in the original post. I will definitely keep researching literature about this.

Comment: Perhaps, what you should do is some *classification*. As you can see, the question is really broad. As you also are aware, every linearization up to a second order will mostly undoubtedly fall into some RLC combination of terms, strictly tied to the second order expansion, adding of course other modes you have not listed here. Also, you missed the fact that some series models are actually equivalent to some other parallel ones, so, your list is, somehow, not well defined.

Comment: I think a deeper (of course also a mathematical) analysis is missing for this classification, to deal with those equivalences, and some specific criteria on when we intend to serialize or parallelize. Are we serializing in equipment, or modules, or components?. Are we linearizing in frequency?. Do you mean *actual* RLC components?. Are you only interested in motors?. What do we seek with this?. At this point, the suggested classification needs much more work, and focused into something concrete, with some real application.